# Change of basis, transition matrix and coordinate vector

Tags: transpose, change-of-basis

Check that **B**={u1 , u2, u3} and **B'**={**u'** 1 , **u'** 2, **u'** 3} are bases in R3, where **u**1=[-3,0,-3]^t **u**2=[-3,2,-1]^t **u**3=[1,6,-1]^t and **u'** 1=[-6,-6,0]^t **u'** 2=[-2,-6,4]^t **u'** 3=[-2,-3,7]^t.

a)find the transition matrix from **B** to **B'**

b)compute the coordinate vector **[w]B** where **w**=[-5,8,-5]^t

c)compute **[w]B'**

I was never taught how to compute this and I'm not too familiar with change of basis